# spring-cloud-config refresh cause thread leaks

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud

dependency:

spring-boot: 1.5.2
spring-cloud: Dalston.SR3

using spring-cloud series:

config erueka zuul bus kafka

I use git webhook and bus to auto refresh zuul routing config. After a week, found out that over 3000 threads were created.
thread dump report here: [report from fastthread](http://fastthread.io/my-thread-report.jsp?p=c2hhcmVkLzIwMTcvMDkvMjcvLS1hcGktZ2F0ZXdheS50eHQtLTItNDctMw==)
And figure out that, everytime when call the `XXX/bus/refresh` endpoint, will cause threads number increase by 7. 
increased thread list:

`DiscoveryClient-0
DiscoveryClient-1
DiscoveryClient-2
...`

After some debugging and tracing, I find that when refresh , 
first will call `EurekaClientConfiguration#eurekaClient` and then call `RefreshableEurekaClientConfiguration#eurekaClient`.
Since annotation of these are `@ConditionalOnMissingRefreshScope` and `@ConditionalOnRefreshScope`, I think only one of them will be invoked.

I am not sure whether or not is this cause the problem. But when I removed config parts, everything works fine. Can anyone help? Thx!

Comment: What does "when I removed config parts" mean?

Comment: I mean remove the spring-cloud-config dependency from pom.xml.
I also had an issue post on github, [click here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/2297)